# push notification in ios using firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

How can I use push notification capabilities in my project? I don't have developer account, I tried this code

```
@IBAction func PhoneSignIn(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Phone number", message: "Is this your phone number? \n \(PhoneOu.text!)", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(self.PhoneOu.text!, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("eror: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            } else {
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                defaults.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVID")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "code", sender: Any?.self)
            }
        }
    }
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    alert.addAction(cancel)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem actually?

Comment: i can't get the otp code to my phone number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you call verifyPhoneNumber:UIDelegate:completion:, **Firebase sends a silent push notification to your app, or issues a reCAPTCHA challenge to the user**. After your app receives the notification or the user completes the reCAPTCHA challenge, Firebase sends an SMS message containing an authentication code to the specified phone number and passes a verification ID to your completion function. You will need both the verification code and the verification ID to sign in the user.

If you don't have a developer account, this is currently not possible using push notifications, better use `reCAPTCHA`:

#### Set up reCAPTCHA verification:

To enable the Firebase SDK to use reCAPTCHA verification:

Add custom URL schemes to your Xcode project:

a. Open your project configuration: double-click the project name in the left tree view. Select your app from the TARGETS section, then select the Info tab, and expand the **URL Types** section.

b. Click the + button, and add a URL scheme for your reversed client ID. To find this value, open the `[![GoogleService-Info.plist][1]][1]` configuration file, and look for the `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` key. Copy the value of that key, and paste it into the URL Schemes box on the configuration page. Leave the other fields blank.
When completed, your config should look something similar to the following (but with your application-specific values):

[image: img]

2. **Optional**: If you want to customize the way your app presents the `SFSafariViewController` or UIWebView when displaying the `reCAPTCHA` to the user, create a custom class that conforms to the `FIRAuthUIDelegate` protocol, and pass it to `verifyPhoneNumber:UIDelegate:completion:`.

Read more:

[Authenticate with Firebase on iOS using a Phone Number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#set-up-recaptcha-verification)